# String toUpperCase

Tags: java

Подскажите нужно перевести все большие буквы в строке в маленькие и наоборот.Ничего кроме как разбить split на подстроки\под\подстроки и сравнить их с массивом из букв не приходит в голову.

Answer (score 5):

Эх, что же вы с таким никнеймом и такие простые вопросы задаёте :) Вариантов масса!

**Вариант №1**

```
class ReverseCase1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "Hello, World!";

        char[] chars = original.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if(chars[i] > 64 && chars[i] < 91) {
                chars[i] += 32;
            }
            else if(chars[i] > 96 && chars[i] < 123) {
                chars[i] -= 32;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}
```

**Вариант №2**

```
class ReverseCase2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "Hello, World!";

        char[] chars = original.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
            else if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}
```

**Вариант №3**

```
class ReverseCase3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "Hello, World!";

        String reversed = original.codePoints()
            .map(c -> Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

        System.out.println(reversed);
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 вариант это 1.8 java?

Comment: @pavel да, с использованием Stream API и лямбд, которые появились в восьмёрке.

Comment: Почему бы в первом и во втором варианте не использовать тернарный оператор, как и третьем, он там гораздо уместнее двойного `if` ?

Comment: @pavlofff мне намного интереснее, можно ли как-то обойтись без тернарного оператора в третьем варианте. Сердцем чувствую, что есть более изящный способ управления потоком, но не могу сообразить какой.

Comment: String reversed = original.codePoints()
                .map(c -> Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c))
                .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) i))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

Answer (score 1):

Ответ кроется в вопросе или я неправильно понял:

[toUpperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--)

[toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--)

UPDATE:
    Вариант если я всё же неправильно понял

[How can I invert the case of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Думаю неправильно.